# How to find non zero minimum array in a 2D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2D matrix as shown below:

```
A = 

1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8193    0.6429    0.4731
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8172    0.6395    0.4696
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8099    0.6285    0.4582
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.7938    0.6066    0.4364
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.7588    0.5675    0.4006
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8527    0.6739    0.5039    0.3477
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8825    0.7371    0.5803    0.4264    0.2807
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.7928    0.6327    0.4838    0.3406    0.2054
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8846    0.7945    0.6560    0.5173    0.3816    0.2469    0.1131
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8598    0.7438    0.6373    0.5194    0.3988    0.2785    0.1522         0
1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.8710    0.7956    0.6954    0.5935    0.4916    0.3856    0.2799    0.1814    0.0834         0
0.7915    0.7845    0.7581    0.6884    0.6159    0.5326    0.4432    0.3500    0.2514    0.1538    0.0838         0         0
0.5972    0.5882    0.5596    0.5085    0.4471    0.3760    0.2967    0.2137    0.1163         0         0         0         0
0.4208    0.4116    0.3836    0.3389    0.2881    0.2274    0.1540    0.0919         0         0         0         0         0
0.2629    0.2536    0.2244    0.1755    0.1388    0.0915         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
0.1235    0.1155    0.0850         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

I want to remove its zero arrays and then find the minimum value of each column and put those minimum values in a vector.

I just used `find(A ~= 0)` but it's not working.

How can I do that?

Comment: 2 things: 1) Please post the matrix as text and NOT as an image. 2) Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the zeros? Running min column-wise on the matrix A(A>0) will do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all of the zeroes with `NaN`, then apply [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) to each column independently.  Setting values to `NaN` in a matrix / vector allows `min` to **ignore** those values, so you'd effectively be ignoring the zeroes.  Assuming that your matrix is in `A`, do this:

```
Anan = A;
Anan(A == 0) = NaN;
out = min(Anan, [], 1);
```